# How to upload a video through Linkedin API? Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch Error while uploading the asset

Tags: video, upload, postman, linkedin-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#register-an-upload

There are 3 steps to upload a video according the linkedin documentation.

1. Register upload Request.

I am able to successfully register upload request.

**Response :**

```
{
    "value": {
        "uploadMechanism": {
            "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest": {
                "headers": {
                    "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
                    "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms",
                    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                },
                "uploadUrl": "https://video-uploads-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/KEY1/aws-userUploadedVideo?X-Amz-Algorithm=[ALGORITHM]&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=[CREDENTIAL]&X-Amz-Signature=[SIGNATURE]"
            }
        },
        "mediaArtifact": "[ARTIFACT]",
        "asset": "[ASSET]"
    }
}
```

2. Uploading the Asset

**I am using the following curl request to upload the asset**

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://video-uploads-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/KEY1/aws-userUploadedVideo?X-Amz-Algorithm=[ALGORITHM]&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=[CREDENTIAL]&X-Amz-Signature=[SIGNATURE]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  -H 'x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms' \
  -H 'x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' \
  -F upload-file=@/Users/kaushik/Downloads/videoplayback.mp4
```

But getting response with error 403 Forbidden

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

What should i do to succesfully upload video in linkedin.

I have found same question which was asked years ago when linkedin is not supporting video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably using wrong curl, it has nothing to do with api. Try the same in terminal it will work.